# "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect." for new paid developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

"Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect." what does it mean when you are the administrator of your organization, you have just paid, and been accepted into the developer program and you have waited half a day, and you still cant sign in to iTunes connect?

[image]

After signing into the paid developer account, and clicking on "People" I am sent to another sign in screen that doesnt let me in:

[image]

To rule out possible non applicable answers, please note:

- The developer fee has been paid.developer.apple.com confirms the payment is received
- All those contact documents have been accepted.
- The developer account is not expired, its 1 day old.
- We cant *add* people, because the *add* people is what we are trying to access.

*UPDATE*  48 hours later, still no access and no response from apple support request. Not even sure if it’s something we need to do to fix, or Apple. Everything else in the developer website works, just App Store Connect doesn’t work.

*UPDATE* 72 hours later, still no access. Apple responded though, saying basically "are you sure its not your fault". (clear cookies try again type email)

Comment: So ask Apple about it. What are _we_ supposed to do?

Comment: I've already read the documentation from apple and contacted apple. I am trying to work out what I am missing here.

Comment: But the fact remains that this is not a _programming_ question.

Comment: True, but this website does have a litany or related variants to the question so I figured it would be appropriate: (so similar in fact that I had to word the question carefully so people wouldn’t think it’s a duplicate question)

Comment: What happened when you contacted Apple? I've had good luck with this in the past.

Comment: Update for others who google this error. Its about 30 hours since my dev account was activated but no access yet. Its about 20 hours since I raised the support request to ask what is going on. No update yet — I've not done app work for a while so I am not familiar with what the expected turnaround times should be on this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell, if you 1. have paid the right payments, and 2. you have signed all of the correct agreements, and 3. already have access inside developer.apple.com to create signing certificates, but you don't yet have access to App Store Connect, there is *probably* a problem that can only be resolved by contacting Apple Support.

Aside from the slow turnaround, the apple support team was great, and were able to resolve the problem. (Took a little over 3 business days to resolve)